# Xamarin iOS - Refresh View coming back from another view

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a View 1 (`UIViewController`) which has a button to navigate to a new view - View 2 (`UIViewController`).

I would like to refresh View 1 when user clicks back button from View 2. `UIViewController` does not have `ViewWillAppear` to know the control is back on the view.

How to determine the control is passed on that view

Comment: I am not clear about the question. Do you want to refresh the whole view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `ViewDidAppear` to detect that View 1 is visible again and refresh the view. Do not forget to call the base method too.

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
    //Refresh view here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> UIViewController does not have ViewWillAppear

You don't have the method `ViewWillAppear` on an `UIViewController`?

You could try to use the [UINavigationControllerDelegate](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UINavigationControllerDelegate/) and specifically [WillShowViewController](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UINavigationControllerDelegate.WillShowViewController/p/MonoTouch.UIKit.UINavigationController/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController/System.Boolean/)

Answer (score 0):

1)We can set it with a bool Value.

```
bool viewLoadedAgain =  false;
```

2)Bool value gets 'true' when segue triggers:

```
public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, Foundation.NSObject sender)
        {
            base.PrepareForSegue (segue, sender);

            if(segue.Identifier == "segueToSecondVC")
            {
                viewLoadedAgain = true;

            }
        }
```

3) Perform Refreshing ViewController View.

```
public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
    this.PerformSegue ("segueToSecondVC",this);

    if(viewLoadedAgain ==  true)
    {
        //Use any code as per requirement
        this.View.SetNeedsLayout ();
        this.View.SetNeedsUpdateConstraints ();
        this.View.ReloadInputViews ();
        this.View.SetNeedsDisplay ();

    }
}
```